# No SXA 1.7 ARM Template for Sitecore 9.0.1

Tags: sxa, azure, paas

I have an existing `Sitecore 9.0.1` installation on `Azure PaaS`. I am looking to install `SXA 1.7` on this specific version of Sitecore as Sitecore has outlined this version to be compatible in the SXA 1.7 Installation Guideline.

However, there is no out of the box SXA 1.7 topology template available on the https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates.

Is there an alternative to this or what is the recommended approach? Will it be safe to use the SXA 1.7.1 topology template as the installation guideline pointed this version of SXA to be compatible with `Sitecore 9.0.2`?

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore Azure Toolkit has functionality to generate WDP packages from Sitecore packages.
You can therefore use this instead of using WDP packages for SC 9.0.2.

You can find Azure Toolkit here:
https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Azure_Toolkit.aspx

Documentation can be found here:
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sat/20/sitecore-azure-toolkit/en/sitecore-azure-toolkit.html

Here are precise steps to generate WDP package:
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sat/20/sitecore-azure-toolkit/en/web-deploy-packages-for-a-module.html

Comment: Hi Peter. Thanks so much for the tip. I shall test this once my Azure account is re-enabled. Keep you posted on this.